# Como congelar .py to exe con imágenes usando pyinstaller?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

hice mi aplicación con python pero la quiero convertir a .exe, yo puedo lograr la conversión de .py a exe pero no con la imagen. La imagen funciona bien si corro la aplicacion en su formato original que es .py pero cuando la convierto a .exe no funcion. Si as usado pyinstaller me puedes dar alguna recomendacion gracias? Estoy usando pyinstaller 3.2 con python 3.4.1 installdo.

```
photo = PhotoImage(file="pirate.png")
label = Label(window, image=photo)
label.pack()
```

El mensaje de error.

```
    File "lukcid3.py", line 49, in <module>
      File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 3384, in __init__
      File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 3340, in __init__
    _tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "image.png": no such file or directory
```

.spec

```
 a = Analysis(['C:\\Users\\Francesc\\Desktop\\PyInstaller-3.2'],
                 pathex=['C:\\Users\\Francesc\\Desktop\\PyInstaller-3.2\\lukcid3'],
                 binaries=None,
                 datas=None,
                 hiddenimports=[],
                 hookspath=[],
                 runtime_hooks=[],
                 excludes=[],
                 win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
                 win_private_assemblies=False,
                 cipher=block_cipher)
    pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
                 cipher=block_cipher)
    exe = EXE(pyz,
              a.scripts,
              exclude_binaries=True,
              name='PyInstaller-3',
              debug=False,
              strip=False,
              upx=True,
              console=True )
    coll = COLLECT(exe,
                   a.binaries,
                   a.zipfiles,
                   a.datas,
                   strip=False,
                   upx=True,
                   name='PyInstaller-3')
```

Comment: ¿Has creado un fichero `.spec`? En el mismo puedes indicar el nombre de la imagen y la ruta local. Pyinstaller la guardará en un directorio temporal en el `.exe`. Mira aquí: http://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle

Comment: bueno hay un archivo llamado "elnombredemiapplicacion".spec ally es donde tengo que indicar la ruta de la imagen?

Comment: Si lo pegas igual te pueden indicar mejor.

Comment: actualice la pregunta con el .spec @kikocorreoso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba a meter la siguiente línea en tu `*.spec`:

```
datas = [('C:\\ruta\\a\\mi\\imagen.png', 'carpeta/interna/de/imgs')],
```

dentro de `Analysis`. El primer elemento de la tupla es la ruta a tu imagen en local mientras que el segundo es la ruta interna donde quieres que se guarden las imágenes en tu *bundle*. Debería quedar algo así:

```
a = Analysis(
    ['C:\\Users\\Francesc\\Desktop\\PyInstaller-3.2'],
    pathex = ['C:\\Users\\Francesc\\Desktop\\PyInstaller-3.2\\lukcid3'],
    binaries = None,
    datas = [('C:\\ruta\\a\\mi\\imagen.png', 'carpeta/interna/de/imgs')],
    hiddenimports = [],
    ookspath = [],
    runtime_hooks = [],
    excludes = [],
    win_no_prefer_redirects = False,
    win_private_assemblies = False,
    cipher = block_cipher
)
pyz = PYZ(
    a.pure, 
    a.zipped_data,
    cipher = block_cipher
)
exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    exclude_binaries = True,
    name = 'PyInstaller-3',
    debug = False,
    strip = False,
    upx = True,
    console = True 
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    strip = False,
    upx = True,
    name = 'PyInstaller-3'
)
```

Y dinos si te ha funcionado.

Para saber más sobre como usar un fichero de [especificaciones con PyInstaller le puedes echar un ojo a este enlace](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html).

Comment: Si lo acabo de terminar lo vi en otro foro unico que falta en tu explicación es que tengo que hacer pyinstaller al .spec

Comment: Actualiza tu pregunta a lo mejor otra persona este confundido como yo en el futuro

Comment: @Francesc Añadido. Como no sabía cómo estás usando PyInstaller obvié esa parte. :-)